# angular google directive for bubble chart

Tags: angularjs, charts

Is there a way to make google Bubble chart using AngularJs Google Chart Tools directive. Currently in their official document, only support following charts:

- Annotation Chart
- Bar Chart
- Column Chart
- Gauge
- Hide A Series
- Multi-Chart Example
- Pie Chart

How can I use this to make bubble chart ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

google charts support [bubblechart](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/bubblechart) , the angular google directive is generic so , you can put `$scope.chartObject.type="BubbleChart";` and the right `$scope.chartObject.data`.